# bad props usage could someone help me

Tags: reactjs

all this renders are components but i get this error pls any help

Warning: Unknown prop `video` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details,

MSO.js

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div id="menusearch"></div>
                <MenuSearch />
            <div id="videoplayer"></div>
                <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
            <div id="videolist"></div>
                <VideoPlayer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

VideoList.js

```
render(){
    const videolista = this.props.videos.map((videos) => {
        return <videoRow key={videos.etag} video={videos}/>
    })
    return(
            <div className="list-group">
                {   videolista    }
            </div>
    )
}
```

VideoRow.js

```
render(){
    return(
            <div className="list-group">
                <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{this.props.video}</a>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All functions render as component and most be capitalized wow didnt see that coming